# Saving a function return inside a const is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am challenging myself on a small JS application, its about a few Basketball Teams where i am calculating the average score of three games there are playing.
I am stuck on a basic thing, i don't get it.

First here is the code:

```
// simple stringbuilder function
function appendStringBuilder(string, tag) {
  return document.querySelector(tag).append(string);
}

// function calculates average score of team
function avgScoreCalc(obj) {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  let avgSum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (Number.isInteger(values[i])) {
      avgSum += values[i];
    }
  }
  avgSum = avgSum / 3;
  return Math.round(avgSum);
}

function challenge2(ObjName, teamName, firstGame, secondGame, thirdGame) {
  var ObjName = {
    teamName: teamName,
    firstGame: firstGame,
    secondGame: secondGame,
    thirdGame: thirdGame,
  };
  avgScoreCalc(ObjName);
  return appendStringBuilder(`${ObjName.teamName}: ${avgScoreCalc(ObjName)} | `, '.code-output-2');
  }

// IS UNDEFINED, WHY? <<<<
const TJohn = challenge2('TJohn', 'Team John', 89, 120, 103);
//----------------------------------------------------------

console.log(TJohn); //<<<< 'undefined'
```

I really just want to save the return of the "`challenge2()`" function inside a simple var. What am i doing wrong?
Debugging says its undefined.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: appendStringBuilder is returning undefined

Comment: You have no function appendStringBuilder(), if you did create one, please add it to your question.

Comment: sorry, forgot to put it in, it was there already. i added it to the code on top.

Comment: [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) returns `undefined`. You probably meant to do

```
function appendStringBuilder(string, tag) {
  document.querySelector(tag).append(string);
  return string;
}
```

Comment: works great thanks. But it didn't looks clean for me the way i did the stringBuilder function. Do you have a idea to optimize my stringBuilder function?

Comment: No, I don't even have any idea of what this function has to do with string building.

Comment: bad function name, this functions should just help me to print out a result string. i wanted to made this as a function to prevent writing the same code output every time. lets just call it a html result print out function.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to rename it to `printToDom`, and have it return nothing. Instead, have `challenge2` return the string that you want, then at the calling site store it in a variable that you can both print to the dom and to the console.

Answer (score 1):

[ParentNode.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) does return nothing, aka `undefined`. As you return the result of that call from `appendStringBuilder`, and return that again to then finally assign it to a variable, it is no surprise that the variable is `undefined` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
It looks like the signature of challenge2 function having ObjName is not of any use as again you are creating a variable inside with same name. Also other functions you are using inside not having any definition.

Find the updated 'challenge2' function which will work for same. (still can be optimized)

// function calculates average score of team

    function avgScoreCalc(obj) {
      const values = Object.values(obj);
      let avgSum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (Number.isInteger(values[i])) {
          avgSum += values[i];
        }
      }
      avgSum = avgSum / 3;
      return Math.round(avgSum);
    }

    function challenge2( teamName, firstGame, secondGame, thirdGame) {

      var ObjName = {
        teamName: teamName,
        firstGame: firstGame,
        secondGame: secondGame,
        thirdGame: thirdGame,
      };

      return `${ObjName.teamName}  :  ${avgScoreCalc(ObjName)}`;

    }

    const TJohn = challenge2( 'Team John', 89, 120, 103);
    //----------------------------------------------------------

    console.log(TJohn);
```